# Excel filter a list based on a value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA and I want to return a list of items that belong to a specific ID, how can I filter the list based on that?

Example:

```
Col A | Col B
1       Apple
1       Banana
2       Apple
3       Apple
1       Coconut
```

If I asked to filter Column B values where Column A = 1, I would get {Apple, Banana, Coconut}

How can I do that?

Comment: You can do this without VBA...You can use either AutoFilter or a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to have a "header" row as the first one and then you can use AutoFilter() as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim vals As Variant

    vals = GetValues(1) '<--| get the array with values corresponding to ID=1
End Sub
```

which use the following function:

```
Function GetValues(ID As Variant) As Variant
    Dim iVal As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ID
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                ReDim vals(1 To .Count)
                For Each cell In .Cells
                    iVal = iVal + 1
                    vals(iVal) = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
                Next
            End With
            GetValues = vals
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: what's the 103 value ?